# How do I fix an error when deploying Rails app to heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, heroku

I am trying to deploy my Rails app to heroku but am getting an error, which is below.  I am also incuding my gemfile.

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.12'
gem 'dynamic_form', '1.1.4'
gem 'json','1.7.7'
gem 'httparty', '0.10.2'

group :development do
    gem 'sqlite3'
end

gem 'bootstrap-sass', '2.1'

group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'client_side_validations'

group :test, :development do
  gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 2.11'
end

group :test do
  gem 'capybara', '1.1.2'
  gem 'factory_girl', '2.6.4'
end
gem 'devise', '2.1.0rc'

group :production do
  gem 'pg', '0.12.2'
end
```

## error

Gem files will remain installed in /tmp/build_232b9vaemz20q/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sqlite3-1.3.7 for inspection.
       Results logged to /tmp/build_232b9vaemz20q/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sqlite3-1.3.7/ext/sqlite3/gem_make.out
       An error occurred while installing sqlite3 (1.3.7), and Bundler cannot continue.
       Make sure that `gem install sqlite3 -v '1.3.7'` succeeds before bundling.
 !
 !     Failed to install gems via Bundler.
 !
 !     Heroku push rejected, failed to compile Ruby/rails app

To git@heroku.com:warm-chamber-7399.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heroku doesn't support SQLite databases. You need to use `PostgreSQL` on production.

```
group :production, :staging do
  gem "pg"
end

group :development, :test do
  gem "sqlite3-ruby", "~> 1.3.0", :require => "sqlite3"
end
```

Go through this link : [Sqlite3 Does Not Support Heroku](https://getsatisfaction.com/railstutorial/topics/sqlite3_not_supported_with_heroku)